# design pattern issue

Tags: design-patterns

i am completely new to design patterns... below is the architecture wht i am following..can anyone pls tell me the pros and cons of it...

- Entities -> consists of properties with get/set method
- DAL -> Data access layer -> handles the db execution
- BLL-> Business logic layer
- UI -> the user interface

Lets say we have a customer table with `customerid`,`customername`

So Entities will have get set properties for `customerid` and `customername`

- UI -> will pass the `customerid` and `customername` to BLL
- BLL-> do validation pass it to DAL
- DAL -> will push it to database

I dont really understand of having so many layers...

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are not really defined by the topics you are mentioning. Make no mistake, they are a part of the solution.

**A design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design.**

Often times it is hard to conceptualize why a design pattern is worth the effort until you finally begin coding a project that meets some of these criteria:

- Modestly complex application
- Multiple programmers involved
- Testing is important during implementation
- Scaleability of your application is important in the future (with unknown limits to how much it needs to scale)
- Same goes for the flexibility of the app

You can also look at the list above as some of the many reasons programmers opt for a Design Pattern under certain scenarios. It is important to realize that althought patterns are cool and often look like brilliant solutions, you should heavily weigh whether it is needed in your particular project. Otherwise you could easily become afflicted with **Pattern Mania**.

=D

Answer (score 1):

A great book on design patterns is O'Reilly's "Head First Design Patterns". It helped me tremendously. It shows you how good design and separation of concerns make maintenance and re-use easier. One con to having multiple layers is that it requires more planning up front, but more than makes up for it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The layers you're describing each have a separate role:

- the UI presents to the user and allows user interaction
- the BLL validates user input & data sanity
- the DAL provides a consistent/coherent interface to the database

Separating data validation from the interface has many advantages - security, for example, or the possibility to (radically) change the user interface without changing the core of your application. This is one of the basic premises of the Model-View-Controller design pattern.

Separating database access from the business logic allows you to change your database implementation, your database schema, etc. without changing the business logic at the same time, thus de-coupling the two,

De-coupling functionally different parts of an application allows you to test those parts independently, maintain them (relatively) independently, etc. In the long run, it avoids maintenance head-aches and, often, bugs.